# How to change PDF name when piping to pdflatex?

Tags: pdftex, lhs2tex

I use MiKTeX on Windows, and `lhs2tex` to write Haskell programs using Literate Programming. When I run

```
lhs2tex code.lhs | pdflatex
```

on CMD, I get a PDF output called "texput.pdf", but I want it to be named the same as the original file, "code.pdf".

I tried adding `%& -job-name=code` to the .lhs file but that didn't work. I also tried

```
lhs2tex code.lhs | pdflatex -job-name=code
```

but it failed. Of course I could do

```
lhs2tex code.lhs > code.tex
pdflatex code.tex
```

but I'm trying to do it in a single command line. Is that possible?

Comment: Works for me, but with `-jobname` instead of `-job-name`. On the other hand, probably you'll want to use some nice LaTeX features like cross-references, or table of contents, so you'll have to run `pdflatex` twice on the LaTeX source. In this case having a file and not using a pipe would be better I suppose.

Comment: @SergeiGolovan That didn't work for me. Still, you're right, I always use cross-references, but not this time. Right now I'm taking this chance learn more about Literate Haskell and ``lhs2tex``. And this is actually the first time I use piping too.

Comment: What didn't work? Have you tried `lhs2tex code.lhs | pdflatex -jobname=code`? (BTW, it's `lhs2TeX` in my system).

Comment: @SergeiGolovan That's right. I mean that using ``-jobname`` instead of ``-job-name`` didn't work. And I just noticed I can use both ``lhs2tex`` and ``lhs2TeX``.

Comment: Then don't do that I guess. If you want to use a single command to build PDF then write a Makefile.

Comment: I don't have lhs2tex but I tried with `echo "\documentclass{article}\begin{document} a \end{document}" | pdflatex --jobname=pipe` with a current miktex in win10 on a normal windows command line and the piping worked fined and wrote a pipe.pdf.